# How to update gems in Ruby for Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using Ruby's Command prompt. I cannot install any update, but internet navigation seems to be working.

I have no proxy here.

```
C:\Windows\System32>gem update activesupport
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

What could be wrong?

Here is my environment:

```
C:\Ruby\bin>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/wmj/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: does ping work? ping rubygems.org? Saying this because errors you're getting are associated clearly with a proxy or something with your connection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First run (with administrator privileges):

```
gem update --system
```

Then run the update for activesupport.
I have that error one time, because i was behind a proxy, in that case, put:

```
gem update --http-proxy http://web.proxy.uri --system
```

Comment: yes I tried gem update --system and it is not working. really weird! SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: gem update system

would be great, but Windows can't find Gem to run this command. 

Installed new rubygems manually: download, extract then ruby setup.rb. Was successfully, from terminal I see gem version is 1.8.6.  But still everything want to use my old gems.

How to remove old gem version? And howto add new gem path?

Thanks