# Issue installing gems on windows 7 with proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install ruby on windows 7 behind a proxy.

I have looked at various forums and have set (i think) the http_proxy successfully (see below)

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http:username:password@http://proxyhere.com:8080
```

however, i now get the following error trying to install a gem:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A possible duplication of this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319212/how-to-update-gems-in-ruby-for-windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `HTTP_PROXY` syntax needs to be URI:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=scheme://user:pass@host:port/path
```

`scheme` could be `http` or `https` and on some cases `path` could be absent.

No browser (or RubyGems) will accept as valid URL the one you provided.

So in your case:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxyhere.com:8080/
```

Hope that helps

Comment: And what if I what to remove the proxy settings while working on a network without proxy? What should I do?

Comment: @ben if proxy is already set, you need to do: `SET HTTP_PROXY=` which will unset the environment variable. You can also check your permanent environment variable settings (Google is your friend on how to change that)

Answer (score 5):

At work i have a proyx also, `SET HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyhere.com:8080` works there, so try it without usename/password. It depends on the type of proxy i presume.

You could also use:

```sh
gem install --http-proxy http://proxyhere.com:8080 $gem_name
```

See this for more info [How do I update Ruby Gems from behind a Proxy (ISA-NTLM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm)