# Ruby on Rails installation on Windows via Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PNE6.png) i try but can do this ...

how to set proxy , really i don't know

also see stack overflow and other forums...
here links:

[Issue installing gems on windows 7 with proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633557/issue-installing-gems-on-windows-7-with-proxy)

but can not get it how to set variable , which proxy give(ip..browser or other) and how set port ,
plz can anyone simple way explain how to solve...

Thanks in advance...!!!
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
    bad URI(is not URI?): http://http_proxy = username:password@proxyserver:port

Comment: What command are you running to install it?

Comment: gem install rails

Comment: where is this coming from? `http://http_proxy = username:password@proxyserver:port`

Comment: i don't know i upload screenshot// see in start line ..

Comment: is there any video tutorial for this ...how to fix it...