# "Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0) in any repository... SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known"

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am getting

```
"Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0) in any repository... SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known" error while trying to install cucumber. PFB the details:

"ruby -v"

ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]


"gem -v"

1.8.28

"gem install cucumber"

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0) in any repository  
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)                    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)                                                                 


"ruby dk.rb install"  

[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby/Ruby193' 
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby/Ruby193'
```

I have placed Ruby in `C:\Ruby\Ruby193` and `DevKit` in `C:\Ruby\DevKit` paths.

Do let me know what I am missing.

Comment: What's the output form `gem source -l`? Try `gem install cucumber -s http://rubygems.org`

Comment: "gem source -l" gives this:
C:\Documents and Settings\pmv.SRA873>gem source -l *** CURRENT SOURCES ***  
"gem install cucumber -s http://rubygems.org" gives this:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0) in any repository          ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)  
Help me!!! :(:(

Comment: For what i can see you don't have any source you can add by doing this `gem source -a http://rubygems.org` and then try `gem install cucumber`. In the -s option i saw that you didn't put the http:// that can be the problem.

Comment: Hi,
"C:\Ruby\DevKit>gem source -a http://rubygems.org" gives 
Error fetching http://rubygems.org: SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known. (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz) and I have included http in the -s option, just missed it out while posting it here.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try to have a look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319212/how-to-update-gems-in-ruby-for-windows

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to proceed using stackoverflow.com/questions/5319212/.

Comment: "C:\Ruby\rubygems-2.1.11>gem install cucumber --source http://rubygems.org" is throwing        

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to 

download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name 

(https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz) Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

any idea on this??

Comment: Did you read the comments above ? Use "http://". You are skipping the "http://" in the command to install the gem: install cucumber --source http://rubygems.org